# How to set path for images to display it through name with different sequences for executable

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap, executable

I'm trying animate 4 images with different sequences, so I'm wondering how to set path to display images with name and also use this path for executable. Question is, where  I have to save pictures folder, and how to get path  to display images with different sequences through variable name  for excusable file to make it available for other users and do not do it that way:

```
    Bitmap img1, img2, img3, img4;

    img1 = new Bitmap(@"D:\my_doc\folder\images\1.png", true);
    img2 = new Bitmap(@"D:\my_doc\folder\images\2.png", true);
    img3 = new Bitmap(@"D:\my_doc\folder\images\3.png", true);
    img4 = new Bitmap(@"D:\my_doc\folder\images\4.png", true);

    pictureBox1.Image = img1;
```

Comment: You can add images to `Resources.resx` and then use them this way: `Properties.Resources.Image1`. Also you can put images in your output directory and find the in `Application.StartupPath`.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Yes this is what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(VS.80).aspx) to add your images to project resources.

[image]

After adding the images you can write some codes like this:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap img1, img2, img3, img4;

img1 = YourProjectsBaseNamespace.Properties.Resources.img1
img2 = YourProjectsBaseNamespace.Properties.Resources.img2
img3 = YourProjectsBaseNamespace.Properties.Resources.img3
img4 = YourProjectsBaseNamespace.Properties.Resources.img4
```